# Wilson Score for 1-5 star rating in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I found [this](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2015/09/24/how-to-build-a-5-star-rating-system-with-wilson-interval-in-mysql/) really well explained calculation but I really don't know if it's correct or not. I've seen a lot of posts on the subject I havent seen one calculate for 5

the most important part is this:

```
Stars   Negative    Positive    Total
0       0           0           0
1       1           0           1
2       0.75        0.25        1
3       0.5         0.5         1
4       0.25        0.75        1
5       0           1           1

SET new.total = new.positive + new.negative,
  new.stars = ROUND( (((new.positive / new.total) * 4) + 1) * 2, 0) / 2,
  new.lower_bound = ((new.positive + 1.9208) / (new.positive + new.negative) - 1.96 * SQRT((new.positive * new.negative) / (new.positive + new.negative) + 0.9604) / (new.positive + new.negative)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (new.positive + new.negative))
```

which I converted to C# as the following

```
        double posf = model.stars == 1 ?  0 :
                model.stars == 2 ?  0.25 :
                model.stars == 3 ?  0.5 :
                model.stars == 4 ?  0.75 : 
                model.stars == 5 ?  1 : 0;
            double negf = model.stars == 1 ?  1 :
                model.stars == 2 ?  0.75 :
                model.stars == 3 ?  0.5 :
                model.stars == 4 ?  0.25 : 
                model.stars == 5 ?  0 : 0;

            rating.positif += posf;
            rating.negatif += negf;
            rating.ratingcount += 1;
            rating.ratingavg = Math.Round((((rating.positif / rating.ratingcount) * 4) + 1) * 2, 0) / 2;
            rating.calcSort = ((rating.positif + 1.9208) / (rating.positif + rating.negatif) - 1.96 * Math.Sqrt((rating.positif * rating.negatif) / (rating.positif + rating.negatif) + 0.9604) / (rating.positif + rating.negatif)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (rating.positif + rating.negatif));
```

Can someone help me if this coding is correct conversion and if the sql version is actually correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the lower-bound value as a double, there is no need to round it. The C# function can be turned into something like this:

```
    private static double WilsonAlgorithm(double positive, double negative)
    {
        return ((positive + 1.9208) / (positive + negative) -
                1.96 * Math.Sqrt((positive * negative) / (positive + negative) + 0.9604) /
                (positive + negative)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (positive + negative));
    }
```

(credits to: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html, most of it came from the sql code on his page)

To convert from stars --> positive/negative, you can calculate them without over-using the ternary operator for readability.

```
    // constants
    const int maxRating = 5;
    const int minRating = 1;
    const double shareRating = 0.25;
    // conversions
    var stars = 5;
    var positive = (stars - minRating) * shareRating;
    var negative = (maxRating - stars) * shareRating;

    // .. 

    // usage?
    var lowerBoundRating = WilsonAlgorithm(totalPositive, totalNegative);
```

Comment: Thank you for the edits. What about the math and formulas are they correct in the url? Thats actually more important.